# Usar string e inteiro em lua

Tags: lua

Bem tenho uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
{
        Number: 15007       Name: "Variance"        Value:  35

}
```

Antes eu usava um formato txt que era assim:

```
15007,Variance,35
```

O código em C era mais ou menos assim:

```
void read_names(void) {
    struct st *table;
    int var = 0;
    const char *str = NULL;

    table->number = var;
    table->name = str;
    table->value = var;

    return;
}
```

Quero mudar para lua agora, eu poderia usar libconfig, mais já usei uma vez e a mesma é muito limitada, um exemplo em lib se eu fosse fazer a tabela acima:

```
void read_names(void) {
        struct st *table;
        int var = 0;
        const char *str = NULL;
        config_setting_t *names = .........

        table->number = config_setting_lookup_int(names, "Number", &var);
        table->name = config_setting_lookup_string(names, "Name", &str);
        table->value = config_setting_lookup_int(names, "Value", &var);

        return;
}
```

Dessa forma acima eu conseguiria fazer a leitura da tabela que postei no inicio do tópico.

Porém quero usar lua, o que quero saber como eu uso da mesma forma da lib e permita eu usar inteiros e string nos nomes Number, Name e Value, por exemplo:

```
table->number = função_lua(L, "Number", &var);
```

Caso a escrita não possa ser dessa forma, leve em consideração que foi apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Não dá para entender o que você está fazendo e o que está querendo fazer. Você precisa [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais informações que sejam relevantes para o problema.

Comment: Editei, o que eu quero saber é como eu posso chamar o lua para números na função  `table->number =` no caso essa função teria que ler o Value da tabela.

Comment: Você quer saber qual é a função para usar um valor que seja numérico ao invés de uma *string* como foi feito com `Name`?

Comment: sim, só que teria que ler Value: seria igual uma leitura em C que você faz `printf("Value %d\n", table->name);`

Comment: O que você colocou está fazendo o que você quer? Porque não deveria. O que você está descrevendo que você quer é diferente do que o código está fazendo. Talvez se colocar em **detalhes** o que você está fazendo, onde está querendo chegar e um código completo fique mais fácil entender.

Comment: Adicionei novas informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer que os índices da tabela possam ser do tipo número e cadeia "string":

Você pode manipular os índices da tabela normalmente apenas use o separador `,`

Teste o código abaixo na rede: https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

```
tab = { 'indice1', cad = 'cadeia', 'indice2'}
print(tab[1],tab.cad,tab[2])
-- indice1  cadeia  indice2
```